# Magento 2.3: Write unit test for Observer

Tags: magento2.3, unit-tests, phpunit

I am writing a unit test for an observer invoking **sales_order_place_after** event.

### SendOrderToVenuePay  Observer

```
class SendOrderToVenuePay implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        \Sample\Module\Helper\Credit\Config $helperCreditConfig,
        \Sample\Module\Helper\Credit $helperCredit,
        \Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomer $currentCustomer,
        \Sample\Module\Api\CreditManagementInterface $creditManagement
    ) {
        $this->helperCreditConfig = $helperCreditConfig;
        $this->helperCredit = $helperCredit;
        $this->currentCustomer = $currentCustomer;
        $this->creditManagement = $creditManagement;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        if ($this->currentCustomer->getCustomerId()) {
            // do some good stuff with order
        }
    }
}
```

### SampleObserverTest

```
class SampleObserverTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        $objectManager = new ObjectManager($this);

        $this->helperCreditConfigMock = $this->createMock('\Sample\Module\Helper\Credit\Config');

        $this->helperCreditMock = $this->createMock('\Sample\Module\Helper\Credit');

        $this->currentCustomerMock = $this->getMockBuilder('\Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomer')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->setMethods(['getCustomerId'])
            ->getMock();

        $this->creditManagementMock = $this->createMock('\Sample\Module\Api\CreditManagementInterface');

        $this->sendOrderToVenuePay = $objectManager->getObject(
            'Sample\Module\Observer\SendOrderToVenuePay',
            [
                'helperCreditConfig' => $this->helperCreditConfigMock,
                'helperCredit' => $this->helperCreditMock,
                'currentCustomer' => $this->currentCustomerMock,
                'creditManagement' => $this->creditManagementMock
            ]
        );
    }

    public function testExecute()
    {
        $this->eventMock = $this->createPartialMock(
            \Magento\Framework\Event::class,
            ['getOrder']
        );
        $this->eventObserverMock = $this->createMock(
            \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer::class
        );
        $this->eventObserverMock
            ->expects($this->any())
            ->method('getEvent')
            ->willReturn($this->eventMock);

        $this->eventMock
            ->expects($this->atLeastOnce())
            ->method('getOrder')
            ->willReturn($this->returnSelf());

        $this->currentCustomerMock
            ->expects($this->atLeastOnce())
            ->method("getCustomerId")
            ->willReturn($this->any());
    }
}
```

Following block of code

```
$this->currentCustomerMock
    ->expects($this->atLeastOnce())
    ->method("getCustomerId")
    ->willReturn($this->any());
```

throws

```
1) Sample\Module\Test\Observer\SampleObserverTest::testExecute
Expectation failed for method name is equal to "getCustomerId" when invoked at least once.
Expected invocation at least once but it never occurred.
```

and following block of code

```
$this->eventMock
    ->expects($this->atLeastOnce())
    ->method('getOrder')
    ->willReturn($this->returnSelf());
```

throws

```
1) Sample\Module\Test\Observer\SampleObserverTest::testExecute
Expectation failed for method name is equal to "getOrder" when invoked at least once.
Expected invocation at least once but it never occurred.
```

Please help what I am doing wrong? Since I am new to PHPUnit I am unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never execute your object i.e. `$this->sendOrderToVenuePay`, to execute this you have to initiated the observer object so right after `$this->sendOrderToVenuePay` declaretion under **setUp()** initiate observer object like below

```
$this->event = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
$this->observer = new \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer(['event' => $this->event]);
```

2nd, replace everything in testExecute with the following code

```
$this->currentCustomerMock->expects($this->atLeastOnce())
    ->method("getCustomerId")
    ->willReturn(1);

$this->assertEquals($this->sendOrderToVenuePay, $this->sendOrderToVenuePay->execute($this->observer));
```

The test will be passed successfully but remember if you want to **do some good stuff** with the order then you must assign an order to event observer to perform further tests, add following lines just before the `$this->assertEquals`

```
/** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order | \PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\MockObject $orderMock */
$orderMock = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::class)
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->getMock();
$this->event->setOrder($orderMock);
```

Since we are using `\Magento\Framework\DataObject` so setOrder will act as a magic setter.